# Having an issue while scraping the print preview page using selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

Having an issue to scrape the print preview page and export it into the CSV file. When clicking on the Print Preview url instead of providing only text data it is also giving the source code in it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import pandas as pd
import os
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from pandas import ExcelWriter
url = 'https://maharerait.mahaonline.gov.in'
chrome_path = r'C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Scripts/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path)
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 
    20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='search- 
    pro-details']//a[contains(.,'Search Project Details')]"))).click()
Registered_Project_radio= WebDriverWait(driver, 
    10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"Promoter")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",Registered_Project_radio)
Application = driver.find_element_by_id("CertiNo")
Application.send_keys("P50500000005")
Search = WebDriverWait(driver, 
     10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"btnSearch")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",Search)
View = [item.get_attribute('href') for item in 
driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")]
print(View)
print(View)
driver.get(View)
request = urllib.request.Request(View)
html = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html , 'html.parser')
print(soup.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
View = [item.get_attribute('href') for item in 
driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")]
```

is list a list eg.  `['https://maharerait.mahaonline.gov.in/PrintPreview/PrintPreview?q=MB0agrub1IW1Z63O5lldJdHpk6le6np5EB3HZ3jy8r7qPsLpYPdQwJzwE0S5LXG3fqQe%2fUe6HTGYmXstD%2bcYtATvmObra1R4xBa7L235mdTlmH0wHJPnps0ZXvbDMZxA0Hf9fxpOLM%2ba3Ad13hq9M1bp8Agvb%2bCLA3KOgpoYwr0%3d', None, None, None, None]`
 which is containt ulr and `None` element.

Replace your code after `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",Search)` statement to below code:

```
View = [item.get_attribute('href') for item in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a") if
        item.get_attribute('href') is not None]
for url in View:
   request = urllib.request.Request(url)
   html = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
   soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
   divPInfo = soup.find("div", {"id": "DivPInfo"})
   title = divPInfo.find("div", {'class': 'x_panel'}, recursive=False).find("div", {'class': 'x_title'}).find(
      "h2").text.strip()
   x_contentObject = divPInfo.find("div", {'class': 'x_panel'}, recursive=False).find_all("div", {'class': 'col-md-3'})

   my_dict = {title: {x_contentObject[0].text.strip(): x_contentObject[1].text.strip()}}
   print(my_dict)
```

O/P:

```
{'General Information': {'Information Type': 'Other Than Individual'}}
```

Comment: @P.D `print(soup.text)` it's print HTML body text if you want to scrap data in a good format then scrap website data like updated above code.

Comment: @P.D I merge my code with your code after `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",Search)`  statement and remove your code, it's working.

Comment: @P.D You should learn Beautifulsoup to scrap static website page data.https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: @ bharatk- Can you please suggest for the question related to your answer I am having some issue so posted another question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57251987/get-the-generalised-code-to-scrape-the-data-directly-from-the-print-preview-page

Comment: Hey Can you please look into this below link question    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67947409/want-to-scrape-all-the-specific-href-from-the-a-tag

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here

driver.get(View)
div_2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='fldFirm']").text
print(div_2)
table = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)
#print(table)
#df.to_csv("trial.csv", sep=',',index = False)
div_3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='DivProject']").text
print(div_3)
file2 = open("MyFile2.txt","w")
file2.writelines(div_3)
```

Comment: read_html function scrap only table data, not the whole page.

Comment: if you want to save data into `csv file` try this `table.to_csv("MyFile2.csv")`

Comment: source page has multiple tables, you should iterate by for loop and save data into a diff-2 CSV file.

Comment: no need to required `driver.get(View)` to get page dom, just try `tables = pd.read_html(url)` will give you also the same result.

Answer (score 0):

From reference to above Code, I Want to Scrape the second heading (FSI Details)from the div of id =  DivProject .But I am unable to get the Second heading.

```
enter code here
divPInfo2 = soup.find("div", {"id": "DivProject"})
Project_title1 = divPInfo2.find("div", {'class': 'x_panel'}, 
   recursive=False).find("div", {'class': 'x_title'}).find(
  "h2")[1].get_text(strip=True)
print(Project_title1)
```

Comment: @ bharatk  - Please assist some solution